# problema con friend

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema con el compilador g++ que me muestra un error "po_bi was not declared in this scope" sin embargo al compilar con msvc me compila sin problema, como puedo solucionar este error? El código se compone de 3 partes: complejo.h, complejo.cpp y main.cpp.
complejo.h

```
#if !defined(_COMPLEJO_H_)
#define _COMPLEJO_H_
class CComplejo {

    friend CComplejo po_bi(const double mod, const double alfa);

private:
    double real;
    double imag;
public:

    explicit CComplejo(const double r = 0, const double i = 0)
            : real(r), imag(i) {}
};

#endif // _COMPLEJO_H_
```

complejo.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "complejo.h"

CComplejo po_bi(const double mod, const double alfa)
{
    return CComplejo(mod * cos(alfa), mod * sin(alfa));
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "complejo.h"

int main()
{
    CComplejo d;

    double mod = 9.9;
    double alfa = 4.5;

    d = po_bi(mod, alfa);

}
```

Comment: En `complejo.cpp`, tienes el nombre mal. Es `CComplejo po_bi( const duble mod, const double alfa ) { ... }`.

Comment: @Trauma gracias por la corrección, en el código original lo tengo bien fue al editarlo aquí.

Comment: @Trauma manda truco, busqué en google antes y probé la misma solución y seguía sin funcionar y ahora que doy ctrl+s funciona, tengo ganas de tirar el ordenador..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución pasa por declarar la función po_bi después de la declaración de la clase en el archivo complejo.h tal que así:

```
#if !defined(_COMPLEJO_H_)
#define _COMPLEJO_H_
class CComplejo {

    friend CComplejo po_bi(const double mod, const double alfa);

private:
    double real;
    double imag;
public:

    explicit CComplejo(const double r = 0, const double i = 0)
            : real(r), imag(i) {}
};
CComplejo po_bi(const double,const double);

#endif // _COMPLEJO_H_
```